# Is there any easy way to get one commit per feature in master instead of rebase with squash

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-rebase, git-squash

I have created a feature branch against master branch 2 months back. Updated the feature branch several times in the meanwhile and almost each time I had some conflicts while merging. Fixed those and pushed to feature branch.

Now the problem is, in our org we need to have only one commit for one feature, my current feature branch is having 37 commits(including merge commits).

While I was rebasing I have to resolve commits on each commit I am picking to squash, is there any easy way around to rebase the feature branch with master branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have only one commit per feature in your master you shouldn't use `git rebase`.
Use `git merge` with `--squash` option instead:

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash feature/feature_name
```